# Advanced Boot Options menu opens every time I try to boot up my Acer Aspire S3 with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, acer-aspire

Every time I start up my Acer Aspire S3 goes to the Advanced Boot Options menu.

Selecting the 'Start Windows normally' option works fine - the machine boots up normally but it's just annoying that the Advanced Boot Options screen opens every time.

Checked `msconfig` and the Normal start up is selected. All options under Boot are unchecked.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: Have you run Startup Repair a couple of times?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I was only able to find two recommended solutions. 
One was to install a different boot loader.
The second was someone found a way to disable this but they highly recommended against it due to the fact that if you ever have a real problem your done for.

I found that my problem was I wasn't using the shut down from inside the operating system. If you hold the power button to shut it off it will do this every time. However if you stay inside windows to power off it won't do that.

Comment: Thanks @griffin. Always shut down through the Windows option. What alternate boot loaders are there?

Answer (score 0):

Run msconfig and check if Normal startup is selected in the General tab:
 [image: msconfig]